# IOS application permissions

Tags: xcode, permissions, app-store-connect, info.plist

I'm developing my first app and trying to upload it to the app store connect.

In my info.plist I've the key-value:

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>load music for process</string>
```

I'm asking this permission while the app is running.

Should I declare about this permission in the app store connect or the info.plist is enough for the review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just at Info.plist, but you have to explain a little better what you use this consent for, because Apple may not accept Review.